# playing around with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, gcc, ld, ld-preload

I read [this article recently](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html), and I tried overriding the libc printf function with a doing the following for fun :-

- Create an executable that uses printf to print `this is a test`(printer.c)
- Create an c file with a custom puts to print `muhahaha, this is a test`(custom.c)
- Create an object file `gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall custom.c`
- Create an so file `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmystuff.so.1 -o libmystuff.so.1.0.1 custom.o`
- I add the directory which contains the so file into the LD_PRELOAD environment variable. `export LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)`
- Try running printer

I'd imagine that `muhahaha, this is a test` would be printed out but it seems like im doing something wrong. Have I got some concept wrong? Or am I just doing something wrong?

[EDIT]

The code snippets involved are :-

```
// printer.c
int main() {
printf("this is a test");
return 0;
}

// custom.c
void printf(char *t) {
puts("muhahaha, this is a test");
}
```

Comment: How are we to guess, without seeing your code?  (General comment.)

Comment: Apologies, ill make an edit right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to name the library in the LD_PRELOAD environment variable, not the directory.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libmystuff.so.1.0.1
```

Comment: Possible confusion of LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH which can similarly alter behavior if it specifies a directory containing a modified version of a library used by the executable.